# Strange behavior of multi-line code block in the if clause without parentheses

Tags: c++

When I compile the following code snippet and run it, I expect it to print statement at line no. 12 too. But that doesn't happen? Why is that so? How does compiler handles a comment in if block?

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 using namespace std;
  3
  4 int main() {
  5     int a;
  6     if (false)
  7         cout << "This will not be printed." << endl;
  8         cout << "This will be printed anyway." << endl;
  9
 10     if (false)
 11         // comment
 12         cout << "This should also be printed. But not. Why?" << endl;
 13         a = 100;
 14
 15     cout << "a = " << a << endl;
 16 }
```

produces:

```
hyper150:~ 1041$ g++ what_if.cpp
hyper150:~ 1042$ ./a.out
This will be printed anyway.
a = 100
```

Comment: Comments are just ignored. As if they weren't even there. Also, please be kind to your fellow programmers and don't mislead them with indentation like that.

Comment: @ggaur - It is an extremely good idea to get into the habbit of using braces `{}` around code blocks - like those after `if` statemens.

Comment: I guess you think the if without {} applies to the next line. It does not, C++ doesn't really know about lines. It applies to the next statement, which is essentially up the the next ;

Answer (score 4):

There is no trace of comments what so ever in the produced native language code.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 using namespace std;
  3
  4 int main() {
  5     int a;
  6     if (false)
  7         cout << "This will not be printed." << endl;
  8         cout << "This will be printed anyway." << endl;
  9
 10     if (false)
 11         cout << "This should also be printed. But not. Why?" << endl;
 12         a = 100;
 13
 14     cout << "a = " << a << endl;
 15 }
```

And since the condition at line 10 [new code] is never met - the `cout` at line 11 never occures

Answer (score 1):

It's not printed because you have `if(false)` in front of it and `if (false)` never evaluates to true.

Comment: it would be a witty comment, but I don't think it is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler ignores comments.

And one more advice: In `if` statements like this one it's better when you write curly braces even if there is just a single statement.

```
if (false)
    cout << "This should also be printed. But not. Why?" << endl;
```

is better to write like:

```
if (false)
{
    cout << "This should also be printed. But not. Why?" << endl;
    // Most likely you are going to add more statements here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use brackets, the `if` will only take the next expression:

```
if (false)
cout << "This will not be printed." << endl;
cout << "This will be printed anyway." << endl;

if (false)
// comment
cout << "This should also be printed. But not. Why?" << endl;
a = 100;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (false)
{
   cout << "This will not be printed." << endl;
}
cout << "This will be printed anyway." << endl;

if (false)
{
   // comment
   cout << "This should also be printed. But not. Why?" << endl;
}
a = 100;
```

Comments are removed long before the actual compilation.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use braces to surround the conditional result, then the conditional result terminates with the end of the next statement, which usually means the ; character.

But it is not only the ; character, because you can do this (which is really horrible to read):

```
if (true)
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      if (i == 4)
         break;
      else
         h = i;
```

In this case the for loop is the next occurring statement, which is a iteration-statement that terminates after the h=i statement.

Everyone has their own tastes with the bracket conventions - I prefer to use bracketless if statements only if there is only one line under it which does not need a comment (if there are else statements, then I use brackets).

Answer (score 0):

Code optimization is one of the phases of compilation. During this your commented code is removed from the code which actually produces the binary. So it interprets it as

```
if (false)
   cout << "This should also be printed. But not. Why?" << endl;
```

And you have put a false within the if condition so ....you know the consequences.

Comment: It's the preprocessor which strips the comments from the code, I would not name this "code optimization".

Answer (score 0):

Line endings are not significant in C++; the `if` controls the following
statement.  In your second case, the following statement is the output,
so it should not be printed.  Comments are not statements (an are in
fact replaced with white space before actual parsing).  Thus:

```
if ( false ) std::cout << "no" << std::endl;

if ( false )
    std::cout << "no" << std::endl;

if ( false )


    std::cout << "no" << std::endl;
```

will output nothing.